How to generate an Excel file in-memory and stream it out?
I haven't found a way to do the following yet:

Read a very large data set
Write the data to an Excel file (avoid JVM out-of-memory, but ideally don't want to write the whole thing to disk)
Upload it in parts (to S3 in my case)

Hoping to do all those piece by piece (read some, generate some, write some, repeat).
But haven't figured out if I can both avoid memory problems and avoid writing to disk. Something like this could maybe work? :

Incrementally read the data using pagination
Apache POI Streaming looks like a good way to generate it in memory
Use AWS S3 multipart upload to transfer it incrementally

But (2) seems to be a problem:
Apache POI streaming keeps a limited number of rows in memory which is great, but the end result is still flushing the workbook to file.
Has anyone done something like this before? (And is it even possible given that Excel is a binary format a collection of zipped XML files?)

can you use CSV?

No, CSV is not an option here unfortunately.

binary format? Looking at the API, I see that an SXSSFWorkbook manages an XSSFWorkbook, so I'd expect the resulting xlsx file to be a compressed zip file containing XML text.

Yeah, you're right. Been doing more digging and it is zipped xml files. That might change things, if zipping is ...transitive? Need to see if zipping multiple files separately can get the same result as zipping a collection of files. Or I guess I'd need to zip chunks of xml since a full spreadsheet can get too large. Time for more research.

DeferredSXSSFWorkbook may be relevant, but I haven't tried it.

Cool, I hadn't seen that one. Thanks! Will take a look.

Efficiently streaming large documents as they are constructed is a common problem. SXSSFWorkbook provides a good framework using a sliding window model. As a practical matter, finding the optimal approach will require profiling in a particular context.
For reference below, I have updated the example cited to allow adjusting the window size. A variation of this example, used on the command line, can be used to asses the output. The result appears to work seamlessly on any network mounted volume, but the result may depend on the details of this vendor's offering. The experimental DeferredSXSSFWorkbook may be relevant going forward; @PJ Fanning elaborates here.

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.Assert;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78456843/230513
 */
public class StreamTest {

    private static final int N = 1000;
    private static final int W = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // keep W rows in memory, N - W rows will be flushed to disk
        var wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(W);
        var sh = wb.createSheet();
        for (int rownum = 0; rownum < N; rownum++) {
            Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
            for (int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
                String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
                cell.setCellValue(address);
            }
        }
        // Verify that W rows before N - W are flushed and inaccessible
        for (int rownum = N - (2 * W); rownum < N - W; rownum++) {
            Assert.assertNull(sh.getRow(rownum));
        }
        // The last W rows are still in memory
        for (int rownum = N - W; rownum < N; rownum++) {
            Assert.assertNotNull(sh.getRow(rownum));
        }
        var file = new File("sxssf.xlsx");
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            wb.write(out);
        } finally {
            // dispose of temporary files backing this workbook on disk
            wb.dispose();
        }
    }
}


https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java is an example for DeferredSXSSF. You might also like to try writeAvoidingTempFiles method - this removes one place where temp files are used - SXSSF uses different temp files at a different stages. DeferredSXSSF with writeAvoidingTempFiles should use the fewest temp files (and maybe none at all)

I'd written up a little POC based on the DeferredSXSSF example, and confirmed it won't write any temp files with writeAvoidingTempFiles().
But I'm not yet seeing a way to get DeferedSDSSF working with S3 multi-part upload. It's all automatic: generating rows, flushing to output as needed based on the window in memory.
I'd need to somehow detect when a minimum upload amount was written to the output stream (or a corresponding PipedInputStream), in order to manually uploadPart() to S3, right?

Sorry, I don't see an API hook for interim results. I can see the appeal, but you may have to conclude streaming before initiating a multipart upload.

This ended up working for me pretty well. I wrote to a PipedOutputStream, generated the sheet in the main thread and had another thread read from the corresponding PipedInputStream, accumulate a buffer until it was large enough for each multipart upload call.
